# "So far this week" - meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you explain, please, the meaning of **"so far this week"**. I can't understand how to translate it correctly into my native language. I've known that **"so far"** means **"at this particular time"**. So, does "so far this week" means "at this week"? What time this action ("so far this week") started and when it finished (start time of "so far this week" and the end time of it)? Feel free to provide some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So far this week" is the span of time from the beginning of the current week to the current moment. An example context is where someone has been busier than expected *so far*, and there might possibly be more to come, e.g., "So far this week I've already had three meetings, two interviews, and a project review, so I'm hoping I can catch a break this weekend."

Comment: Well, "so far this week" is exactly equal to "on this week", right?

Comment: @Sergey Problem: in your question you said "'so far' means 'at this particular time.'" That's a problematic definition. Instead, "so far" could usually be replaced with "up to now." The "this week" part helps clarify the starting point. ("So far today": from the start of today until now. "So far this year": From the start of the year until now.) "On this week" isn't really a phrase we use to talk about the week we're currently in; it can be used for a "matching" week in history ("On this week last year we went on vacation").